How this transaction was included in the block if CLTV is much larger than a current block height?
So here's transaction in question: 04c2ad1e2ac3651e0cda0d2a3cc4b43434ad45de8330a526ab87aabb67587cc6
It's taproot script is:
OP_PUSHBYTES_32 d4f633eb22227fb319cf064b9f9870123db325999f15ffd2f2c01d653a1a3847
OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY
OP_PUSHBYTES_3 25da0b
OP_CLTV

25da0b equals to 2480651, and it was included in a block with a height 779883.
How did it happen?

25da0b is 776741 in decimal number, as bitcoin script number is a little endian order. BIP62 describes details about script number encoding. It's sign-magnitude with little endian.
